# Moodle File Manager - Crucial part

Tags: moodle

I am trying to show the file uploaded from File Manager mform element. I could store the file to mdl_files. To get the file saved is a bit hard to program. I tried implementing few options from Moodle Forums, but was stuck here. I really hope that someone can provide a solution for Moodle File manager (a crucial part). Could anyone guide me where I went wrong and suggest me to get the fileurl.

```
    <?php     
        require('config.php');
        require_once($CFG->libdir.'/formslib.php');
        
        class active_form extends moodleform {
        
            function definition()   {
                    
                $mform = $this->_form;      
                $fileoptions = $this->_customdata['fileoptions'];
        
                $mform->addElement('filemanager', 'video', get_string('video', 'moodle'), null, 
             $fileoptions);    
             
                $this->add_action_buttons();        
            }
        
            function validation($data, $files) {
                $errors = parent::validation($data, $files);
                return $errors;
            }
        }
 
        // Function for local_statistics plugin.
        function local_statistics_pluginfile($course, $cm, $context, $filearea, $args, $forcedownload, 
        array $options=array()) {
        global $DB;
    
        if ($context->contextlevel != CONTEXT_SYSTEM) {
            return false;
        }
    
        $itemid = (int)array_shift($args);
    
        if ($itemid != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    
        $fs = get_file_storage();
    
        $filename = array_pop($args);
        if (empty($args)) {
            $filepath = '/';
        } else {
            $filepath = '/'.implode('/', $args).'/';
        }
    
        $file = $fs->get_file($context->id, 'local_statistics', $filearea, $itemid, $filepath,$filename);
        if (!$file) {
            return false;
        }
    
        // finally send the file
        send_stored_file($file, 0, 0, true, $options); // download MUST be forced - security!
    }

    // Form Settings

    $fileoptions = array('maxbytes' => 0, 'maxfiles' => 1, 'subdirs' => 0, 'context' => 
                   context_system::instance());
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data = file_prepare_standard_filemanager($data, 'video', $fileoptions, context_system::instance(), 
           'local_statistics', 'video', 0);
    $mform = new active_form(null, array('fileoptions' => $fileoptions));

    // Form Submission

    if ($data = $mform->get_data()) {

        $data = file_postupdate_standard_filemanager($data, 'video', $fileoptions, 
                context_system::instance(), 'local_statistics', 'video', 0);
        $fs = get_file_storage();
        $files = $fs->get_area_files($context->id, 'local_statistics', 'video', '0', 'sortorder', false);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
           $fileurl = moodle_url::make_pluginfile_url($file->get_contextid(), $file->get_component(), 
                      $file->get_filearea(), $file->get_itemid(), $file->get_filepath(),
                      $file->get_filename());
           echo $fileurl;
        }
 
    }
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a quick look through your code and it all looks reasonable, but you've not included the code of the local_statistics_pluginfile() function in local/statistics/lib.php - without that function, Moodle is unable to authenticate any requests from the browser to serve files, so all files will return a 'file not found' message.

Have a look at the documentation for details of what the x_pluginfile function should look like (or look for examples in any of the core plugins in Moodle): https://docs.moodle.org/dev/File_API#Serving_files_to_users

Comment: I had followed your instructions by placing the local_statistics function to lib.php. I couldn't see any effect. Please let me know what I was going wrong in mycode.

Comment: Well, looking at the code a bit more, you've called the form element 'video' - according to the documentation, if you want to use the file_postupdate_standard_filemanager() function then you need to call the element 'video_filemanager'. You also seem to be missing any code to output the form ($mform->display() ). You also have an undefined variable $context - are you missing: $context = context_system::instance() ?

Comment: Hello davo. Finally I got the file link and working good. But the problem is I have repeated values coming from filemanager form element. I could access only the last file, but not all. If th're repeated files coming, what could be the exact format url. Please ley me know